# add hyphen in string using SAS?

Tags: sas

I want to add hyphen between phone number when I convert numeric variable to character variable.

For example: the original one is **7819601330 (numeric)**, need to be **781-960-1330 (character)**

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Picture format!

```
proc format;
picture phone
low-high="000-000-0000";
quit;

data test;
x=1234567890;
y=put(x,PHONE.);
put x= y=;
run;
```